# Dropbox SDK on xcode 5 for iPhone Retina 4-inch 64 bit

Tags: objective-c, 64-bit, dropbox, ios7, xcode5

When I added the SDK to the project the following warning appears but ONLY for 64 bit architecture

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Username/Developer/Project/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Username/Developer/Project/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK (4 slices)
```

Anyone has gotten this error already? if so, any solution?

Comment: when building for iOS it shouldn't look for x86_64 (Intel) architecture, I suspect there's something wacky with your build settings. Check required/valid architecture settings of all targets, they should be set to "armv7 armv7s arm64"

Comment: I already have it like that: [link](http://imgur.com/lRVQyoT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a bit of investigation, it seems like Dropbox has not released the SDK to support the 64 bit architecture.

Other frameworks are having this warning as well, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934043/unable-to-link-googleanalytics-3-01-with-xcode-5-missing-required-architecture) for more information on the GA framework.

Nothing can be done to resolve this but to wait for an official release.

Comment: the DB lib is out: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios
Version 1.3.10, updated January 17, 2014 already supports arm64