# Ignoring file SDWebImage.framework, missing required architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, x86-64, sdwebimage, arm64

I've installed [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) in my Xcode 5 / iOS 7 project, but building gives me the following issue which will result in a fatal exception:

```
ignoring file SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage, missing required architecture x86_64 in file SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage
```

SDWebImage seems to be cause [this issue with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934043/unable-to-link-googleanalytics-3-01-with-xcode-5-missing-required-architecture), and the best resolution seems to be cutting arm64 by using Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s) in one's build settings. I don't really want to do that, and SDWebImage had [this issue blaming libwebp](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/494) which suggested falling back to framework 3.2 temporarily.

I'm running framework 3.5 already. Does anyone know how to resolve this, or am I stuck with these work-arounds?

(Thanks!)

Comment: Hi. That's the "this issue with Google Analytics" that I refer to in my question, which still leaves arm64 excluded.

Comment: I'm not using Google Analytics at all actually, I'm just using the SDWebImage framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now, this is fixed in the master branch, but it is not included in the latest .framework release. What I did to make it work was this:

1) Download the latest release from the master branch (currently https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases/tag/3.5.3)

2) Remove SDWebImage.framework from my project.

3) Copy the source files from the zip (Everything inside SDWebImage + the files NSData+ImageContentType.h and NSData+ImageContentType.m) into my project.

4) Replace the header includes of  to "SDWebImage.../...h"

Might be a better way to do this, but this solved the problem for me. As I understand it,64-bit support will be added to the next proper release.

Comment: Much appreciated! I see it has indeed been released with 3.5.4 over here https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases/tag/3.5.4

Comment: Strange, I still get the same error even after replacing the old .framework with 3.5.4. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases/tag/3.5.4

Is there any way to verify it's the correct version?

Comment: Just a note that the framework release available via Cocoapods has been available since last year now.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was having this issue with the latest version of SDWebImage in 2019, much prefer this manual source code import approach... it's just so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem with SDWebImage 3.7.0 in my case what helped was updating CocoaPods to 0.33.1, then reinstalling SDWebImage pod and cleaning project

Answer (score 1):

Download newest version of SDWebImage (3.7.1.4) can solve this problem

I had this issue too, and done.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try again with "Other Linker Flags" set to -all_load instead of -ObjC</strike>

As per https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/494, there's only a workaround for now, it is definitely a problem with libwebp.

Comment: Sorry, no dice. Still getting the Apple Mach-O Linker warning above.

Comment: The official answer is no 64bit-support because of libwebp

Comment: Thanks, Jeremiah. 64-bit support has now been released so I'm switching to Reason's answer. As per my comment there, this shouldn't be an issue with 3.5.4 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering are you running your app in the simulator? Is there a pressing reason why you must run the simulator using the 64-bit mode? I was having the same problem you are having but it went away as soon as I began using the 32-bit mode. Since it looks like the problem is quite fundamental, perhaps the best thing to do for now is to use the 32-bit mode of the simulator and wait for a fix.